# declare listview in main class findviewbyid not working

Tags: android, xml, android-listview

I made a custom **listview**.Now i want to add **onitemclick** method for listview but for  that its required to declare the listview in **main class**. My xml code for list view is as follows.

```
   <ListView
   android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
   >

</ListView>
```

and if i change the id in the format like **android:id="@+id/list"** then my app crashes..
so suggest me what should i do to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i change the id in the format like android:id="@+id/list" then my
>   app crashes

because if you have declared ListVIew with `@+id/android:list` id in xml then you will need to use `android.R.id.list` for initializing ListView instance.in main class do it as:

```
ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

or if you are extending ListActivity then you can also use `getListView()` method for initializing ListView instance as

```
ListView listview = Current_Activity_Name.this..getListView();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `findViewById(android.R.id.list);` to get the `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do declare

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

then you have to do

```
ListView v = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1)
```

and then

```
v.setOnItemClick(new onItemClickListener(){

     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

     }

});
```

I think you shouldn't use `"@android:id/list"`